# Можно ли в python изменить переменную переданную в аргементе функции

Tags: python

Напрмер есть код

```
def func(a:str):
    a = "anton"
    return

a = "victor"
func(a)
print(a)
```

Вывод будет `victor` но можно как-то изменить переменную в функции?

Comment: В функцию передается не переменная, а ее значение, это не указатели. Просто верните новое значение из функции `a = func(a)`, в функцию добавить `return a`. Другой вариант, передавать в параметр функции что-нибудь сложное, типа объекта класса или контейнер (список, словарь, ...)

Comment: Переменная a, которой присваивается значение "victor", и переменная а, которая в функции, это две совершенно разные вещи. Общего у них только имя. Любое из них можно изменить на какое угодно другое и в выполнении программы совершенно ничего не изменится. Так же, как у Бориса из Новосибирска и Бориса из Симферополя общего только имя Борис. А все остальное разное.

Answer (score 6):

## Почему значение `a` не меняется?

Т.к. `a` - строка, то в функцию передаётся копия значения `a`, а не указатель на неё, соответственно, когда мы меняем значение `a` в функции, мы меняем значение локальной копии, а не глобальной переменной.

Смотрите:

```py
def func(a):
    a = "anton"
    print("внутри функции", id(a))

a = "victor"
print("вне функции", id(a))
func(a)
print("вне функции", id(a))
print(a)
```

Выведет что-то типо

```
вне функции 485256706736
внутри функции 485257302960
вне функции 485256706736
victor
```

`id` показывает место в памяти, где лежит значение переменной и, как видите, вне функции оно одно, а внутри - другое.

## Как можно обойти?

В вашем случае вы можете использовать ключевое слово `global`, чтобы получить и изменить значение глобальной переменной:

```py
def func():
    global a
    a = "anton"
    print("внутри функции", id(a))

a = "victor"
print("вне функции", id(a))
func()
print("вне функции", id(a))
print(a)
```

Выведет что-то на подобии:

```
вне функции 542195432176
внутри функции 542200565424
вне функции 542200565424
anton
```

## Как лучше реализовать?

Метод с использованием `global` - наверняка не лучший способ достичь результата, который вы хотите, и я бы посчитал бы это code smell-ом, потому я предлагаю вам сделать так:

```py
def func(a):
    a = "anton"
    print("внутри функции", id(a))
    return a

a = "victor"
print("вне функции", id(a))
a = func(a)
print("вне функции", id(a))
print(a)
```

Выведет что-то такое:

```
вне функции 486729169712
внутри функции 486730096368
вне функции 486730096368
anton
```

Этот подход намного лучше первого.

---

## FAQ

Что за локальные и глобальные переменные?
Локальные переменные - те, которые "заперты" в каком-то контексте, например:

```py
def func(arg):
    pass
```

Здесь `arg` - локальная переменная, она существует только в контексте функции `func`, и имеет влияние только на этот контекст.

Глобальные переменные - те, котоые мы объявляем в контексте программы:

```py
foo = 5
```

Переменная `foo` - глобалья, т.к. объявлена в контексте программы (модуля, или же без отступа)

Comment: @AndreyYakovich если вам помог этот ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ещё можно передать в функцию mutable объект, например список. И модифицировать элемент этого списка.

Comment: Да, @GrAnd, можно использовать изменяемый объект (либо созданный нами класс, либо встроенный), но в данном случаи в этом мало смысла. + я считаю, что это ненужное усложнение для и так уже не очень простого (для новичков) примера